# how to get mid part of string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I am trying to get mid part of string. My table is like below :

```
id   machine   model
1    lathe     ISO-678-1567
```

I want to get mid part like 678 fro machine model.

Desred output:

```
id   machine   model             midcode
1    lathe     ISO-678-1567      678
```

Currently I am doing same with PHP codwe. But I think it will be better to do in Mysql query itself. Please help me how to do this ?

Comment: Give us some info on the rule you want to use to break up the string. Is it always 3 parts, with dashes in between? Is the middle part always a 3-digit number? And so on.

Comment: yes it's always 3 parts. and middest is 3 digit number

Comment: Note that [MID() is an alias for SUBSTRING()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_mid) so the answers below all basically agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `MID(str,pos,len)` mysql function that will do this.

```
SELECT id,machine,model,MID(model,4,3) as midcode FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 4):

If `model` is always of a fixed length, then you could use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(model, 5, 3) AS 'midcode' FROM Tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a09/1)  using the following query:

```
SELECT id,machine,model,
       left(substring(model,(instr(model,'-')+1)),instr(model,'-')-1) AS midcode
FROM tbl_machine;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for SUBSTR/SUBSTRING: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Specific use would be SUBSTRING(field, start_position, length)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(model, 5, 3) as 'midcode' from Tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

**MID()** - Return a substring starting from the specified position
**SUBSTRING()** Return the substring as specified

Site Reference:  [DOCS OFFICIAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)